# How can I stop a cyclic animation?

Tags: animation, keyframes, fcurves

I animated fish that are swimming in a tank with cyclic fin movement. Now I want the fish to die and their fin movement to stop, but I cant get the cyclic animation to stop without the cycle to dissappear completely.

Is there a way to keyframe a beginning and end of a cyclic animation or some other way to make it stop? All help appreciated!

Comment: Use "restrict frame range"

Comment: @cegaton thank you!